# Proving a given relation is strict partial order and finding maximal simply ordered subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem**

If a and b are real numbers , define$ a\prec b$ if $b-a$ is positive and rational . Show that this is a strict partial order on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**

It is a strict partial order because

It is easy to check that this relation is transitive and non-reflexive .

Maximal simple ordered subsets :$ \mathbb{N},
\mathbb{Q},
\mathbb{Z}$

Please comment whether this solution is right or not.

*Note*

This relation is not comparable .For example 
$1,\pi \in \mathbb{R} $
 but $1\nprec \pi$ and $\pi \nprec 1$.

Comment: As far as I know transitive and non-reflexive are necessary and sufficient for being a strict partial order. Being (non-)comparable plays no part in that matter. Also a linear order is a strict partial order (with an extra property).

Comment: @drhab Answer edited.

Comment: @drhab Is maximal simply ordered subsets correct? Are there any more?

Comment: I think that maximal simply ordered sets are here the sets: $a+\mathbb Q$ for $a\in\mathbb R$ (among them is $\mathbb Q$ but not $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$, they are not maximal).

Comment: Ok. So they are ordered but not maximal. Right?

Comment: E.g. $\mathbb Z$ is simply ordered but can be extended to the larger $\mathbb Q$ which is also simply ordered. So $\mathbb Z$ is not maximal.

Comment: Can a set have more than one maximal order subsets?

Comment: I think so. Maximal means that there is no larger one, but not necessarily that it is the unique largest (which might not exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $a\in\mathbb R$ the set $a+\mathbb Q:=\{a+q\mid q\in\mathbb Q\}$ is evidently simply ordered by $\prec$.

If $x\notin a+\mathbb Q$ then $a$ and $x$ are not comparable so it cannot be that a set $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ exists that is simply ordered and satisfies $a+\mathbb Q\cup\{x\}\subseteq S$.

This proves that $a+\mathbb Q$ is maximal in being simply ordered by $\prec$.

If conversely $M\subseteq\mathbb R$ is simply ordered and $a\in M$ then we find that $b-a\in\mathbb Q$ for every $b\in M$ or equivalently that $M\subseteq a+\mathbb Q$.

Then if $M$ is maximal in being simply ordered by $\prec$ it cannot be that $M$ is a proper subset of $a+\mathbb Q$ so in that case we conclude that $M=a+\mathbb Q$.

Proved is now that a subset $M$ of $\mathbb R$ is maximal simply ordered by $\prec$ if and only if $M=a+\mathbb Q$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$.